# Capture streaming packets in a CSV file using Wireshark

Tags: streaming, export-to-csv, wireshark

I would like to know that is there any option in Wireshark to capture packets in the streaming network dynamically. Since I need to capture packets with out doing the export each time and packets capture automatically in a CSV file without exporting it periodically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) to achieve this.  For example, suppose you want to capture the frame number and source and destination IP addresses of each packet (to keep the example simple), you could use:

```
tshark -i foo -T fields -E separator=, -E quote=d -E header=y -Y ip -e frame.number -e ip.src -i ip.dst > output.csv
```

You can specify as many fields as you want using the `-e` option